# Are Pragma Directives at the beginning of a renderscript necessary?

Tags: android, renderscript

The Pragma Directives like

## pragma version(1) at the beginning of a render-script necessary ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you don't place them there, the compiler will generate an error message. This is so that we can comfortably extend the language in the future (without breaking existing applications).